# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

Tags: swift, core-data

I have this problem: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project,  in line " var body: some View {"

I have no idea what to do, it has been two days since I've tried everything!!
Here is my code:

```
struct Saving_Goals_Page: View {
    
    //this is necessary in order to save items into saving goal entity
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    //saving attributes
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var targetAmount = ""
    @State private var currentAmount = ""
    @State private var category = ""
    @State private var endDate = Date()
    @State private var notes = ""
    
    @State private var showEditSheet = false
    @State private var showInfoSheet = false
    @State private var showCategoryFilter = false
   // @State private var selectedGoal: SavingGoal?
    @State private var selectedCategory: Category? = nil
   

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.white

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Hi, UserName!")
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding(.leading,20)

                    HStack {
                        Text("Welcome back!")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .padding(.leading, 50)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink(destination: NewSavingView(){
                            Text("NEW")
                            
                        }.padding()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                        .cornerRadius(10),
                                                                        
                            Button(action: {
                                // Add action for creating a new saving goal
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "flag")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding(8)
                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(5)
                            },
                            
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showCategoryFilter = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "flag")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(8)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showCategoryFilter) {
                            CategoryFilterView(selectedCategory: self.$selectedCategory)
                        }
                        
                        
                    )}
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.top, 10)

                    Divider()
                    
                    // Fetch the `Saving` attributes
                   let request: NSFetchRequest<Saving> = Saving.fetchRequest()
                   guard let savings = try? viewContext.fetch(request) else {
                       return Text("Failed to fetch savings")
                   }

                    ForEach(savings.filter { (saving: Saving) -> Bool in
                          if let savingGoal = saving as? SavingGoal,
                             let category = savingGoal.category {
                              return category == selectedCategory?.id
                          }
                          return selectedCategory == nil
                      }) { (saving: Saving) in
                    
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(saving.name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text(String(format: "$%.2f LEFT", saving.targetAmount - saving.currentAmount))
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showInfoSheet = true
                                self.selectedGoal = saving
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                            }.sheet(isPresented: Binding(
                                get: { self.showInfoSheet && self.selectedGoal == saving },
                                set: { self.showInfoSheet = $0 }
                            )) {
                                if let saving = self.selectedGoal {
                                    InfoView(isPresented: self.$showInfoSheet, saving: saving)
                                }
                            }

                            Button(action: {
                                self.selectedSaving = saving
                                self.showEditSheet = true
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 25)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showEditSheet) {
                    if let saving = self.selectedSaving {
                        EditGoalView(isPresented: self.$showEditSheet, saving: saving)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Saving Goals")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
                                                
}
```

I tried changing things but still no solution

Comment: I tried to look closer on this but there is so much info missing and so much code that  looks strange it is impossible to come up with a solution to this problem. Some pointers though, you can't execute a fetch request right in the middle of your view code so use a `@FetchRequest` instead. You have a cast between Saving and SavingGoal in one place but at other places you seem to just assign a property of one type with the a value of the other type???. Saving seems to be a core data entity but what is the other and why the casting. _continued..._

Comment: Instead of doing a filter call in your ForEach you should extract that into a computed property returning the filtered array. And finally try to get rid of that Binding declaration used when presenting a sheet, there must be a simpler solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just came across this problem also.  I reverted my code to previous but now the error still occurs on that file.  It makes no sense.